# How do I force all users of a Mediawiki wiki to re-login?

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to require that all authenticated users of a Mediawiki instance re-login. This is MW v1.23 on Linux CentOS 6.5 x64, apache, mysql, memcached.

I'm not sure where PHP is storing the user sessions. I've checked /etc/php.ini, but didn't find anything explicit. I created a phpinfo() page, and found session.save_path unset. Perhaps MW is doing its own thing.

I have access to the code, the mysql database, the filesystem and memcached. Our installation authenticates to Active Directory using the LdapAuthentication extension.

I reviewed all settings in LocalSettings.php and came up empty.

I searched for all variables and their defaults that might influence where session is stored.

I found one solution, which is to change the value of $wgCookiePrefix. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require changing configuration, such as deleting objects, files or database rows.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about managing a self-hosted web application.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Linux CentOS 6.5 x64. I'll edit the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately I went with changing the value of $wgCookiePrefix. This was the simplest method to truly invalidate all user's authentication token cookies.

Deleting the php sess_ files did not force users to have to log in again. Upon next visit, another sess_ file was created and the user remained logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question you haven't changed the default, check where your PHP saves its sessions. In your php.ini file you should probably have lines such as:

```
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler = files

; http://php.net/session.save-path
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

Which will tell you where you can delete the sessions.
Mind you could also decide to store sessions in object cache: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSessionsInObjectCache

Comment: Deleting sess_* files from /tmp does not force re-login. The browser is carrying a cookie which appears to automatically re-auth the user upon their return, creating another sess_* file without requiring the user to log in again. I suspect I need to do something to break the association between the token in the cookie and the Mediawiki instance.

Comment: When I get some time I'll try dipping into the source to see what Mediawiki does with the returning user's cookie if no active session is found. It will likely reveal the connection.

Comment: Did you restart your server after deleting cookies?

Comment: You may also decide to add a hook to logout users https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/UserLoadAfterLoadFromSession

Comment: What's the theory behind restarting the server? You think the sess_ files are being cached in apache memory?

Comment: You might have your sessions cached somehow and usually a restart means you clean your caches (unless you're using a memcached that's not tied to the server). I didn't see any session info in the users table but then again maybe user.user_token field is this thing and upon clearing it you'll force login. I'm not sure, so try first. Good luck :)